# question about node split algorithm in rtree

Tags: r-tree

I recently studied the rtree node splitting algorithm. Among the node splitting algorithms, I read an explanation about the Quadratic algorithm, but I cant still understand the explanation. The Quadratic algorithm aims to minimize the area of two nodes when splitting a node. I'm curious about how the pickseed algorithm is used to minimize the area of the two nodes when the node is split.

Comment: Don't take those three split algorithms too seriously.  They are meant to illustrate that it isn't easy to determine the best split - doing more work may give a better result.  Algorithms that make use of characteristics of the data (logs or poles, for example) may be better.  Bad splits still work, just less efficiently.

Contrary to popular opinion, overlap is not important.  The goal is to minimize the expected number of seeks to a lower subtree - this is minimized by minimizing the total area of the two new nodes regardless of overlap.